# Private Azure PYPI not reachable in azure pipelines run

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, pipenv

I have a project `A` managed with pipenv that depends on another project `B` built with pipenv too. The project `B` is published in the private PYPI. My `Pipfile` looks like

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "https://${USERNAME}:${TOKEN}@MyPrivateRepoUrl"
verify_ssl = true
name = "MyRepoPYPI"
```

When I install `A` locally I have not problems and every works fine (declaring environment variables with `export` command). I have configured an `azure-pipelines.yml` with 2 jobs, first install `A` and testing, and the second one is to build and publish the docker image to the ACR. When I trigger the pipeline, the first job fails with this error:

```
FAIL
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 709, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 692, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1403, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/adminroot/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pymooslotting (from -r /tmp/pipenvzsh1c47crequirements/pipenv-y37q7d_w-constraints.txt (line 11))
No versions found
Were https://pypi.org/simple or https://MyUsername:***@MyPrivateRepoUrl reachable?
```

I'm pretty sure the credentials are set correctly.

**The amazing thing is that if I run the second job, the docker image is built correctly, therefore it is telling me that the credentials to install `B` are being passed correctly.**

here is the part of the pipelines where I install `A`

```
steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.7'
      architecture: 'x64'

  - script: |
      python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
      python -m pip install --user pipenv
    displayName: Install Pipenv

  - script: |
      pipenv lock --clear
      pipenv install --system

    displayName: Install Dev Dependencies

  - bash: pytest -rf

    displayName: Unit test
```

I'm not commiting the lock file, but I have done many tests that include the lock in the repo.

Here is the command for docker Publish (that works fine and do the job)

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build Docker Image
    inputs:
      command: build
      containerRegistry: $(acrRepository)
      repository: samples/execslotting
      inputs:
      tags: |
        latest
        $(tag)
      arguments: '--build-arg USERNAME=$(MyUserName) --build-arg TOKEN=$(MyToken)'
```

The docker image is installing `B`, so in the build I pass `USERNAME` and `TOKEN` vars.

**OBS**: The error message `No versions found Were https://pypi.org/simple or https://MyUsername:***@MyPrivateRepoUrl reachable?`  tells me that the envars are correctly read in the execution of the installation job.

Comment: I'd remove the docker tag if package b succesfully publishes the artifact to your private repo...

Answer (score 0):

[the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#manually-configure-authentication) specify a different push and pull endpoint urls for pip... Try appending `/pypi/simple` to the repo description where you are pulling from.

full url: `https://<your-feed-name>:<your-PAT-key>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_packaging/<your-feed-name>/pypi/simple/`